# Why is it so Slow to Re-register a Failed Service?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

We are using Spring Cloud to implement the API Gateway pattern described in [this great tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/28/the-api-gateway-pattern-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-iv). When we deploy updates to our backend services there is a period of downtime while the API Gateway continues to use old backend service instead of the new one.

In the logs I see errors like this one:

```
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: my-service
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:468) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:81) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:88) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.support.AbstractRibbonCommand.run(AbstractRibbonCommand.java:42) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:299) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:295) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:412) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:375) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:341) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.5.jar:1.5.5]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
... 120 common frames omitted
```

The request finds that the service is not available. But it does not appear to try to refresh its list of backend services from Eureka. Why doesn't this trigger an immediate refresh?

The [documentation for Spring Cloud Netflix](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.2.6.RELEASE/) encourages us to use the default lease renewal time. But, it would greatly help to prevent errors to be able to use a failure to trigger an automatic refresh. Can we configure the service to immediately refresh when an error occurs?